# Matching multiple pattern without knowing if they are in the string

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex in order to match with one pattern and then capture all the year dates following this pattern.
For example, I have the following strings and I am trying to get one regex expression to capture pattern 1 and then the following dates (max 2) if they exist.

```
"'pattern1' foobar 4 foo 1 bar foo 1900 and 2000"  
"'pattern1' foobar 4 foo 1 bar foo 1900"  
"'pattern1' foobar 4 foo 1 bar foo"
```

The following expression matches the first case but not if a date is removed:

```
('pattern1').*?(\d{4}).*?(\d{4})
```

Adding ? after the potential date groups only matches the pattern as it satisfies the expression with no match of dates:

```
('pattern1').*?(\d{4}).*?(\d{4})
```

Hence my issue is not being able to specify that a group can or can not be in the expression but match if it is

Comment: You could make both parts optional `('pattern1')(?:.*?(\d{4})(?:.*?(\d{4}))?)?` https://regex101.com/r/WutZ4y/1

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could make the both parts optional and use word boundaries around the digits to prevent them being part of a larger word.

If you want to match more years, you would have to add more optional groups. In that case, I would suggest using an approach like in the answer of @[Alexander Mashin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64523059/5424988).

```
('pattern1')(?:.*?(\b\d{4}\b)(?:.*?(\b\d{4}\b))?)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6exHSt/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* solve your problem with *one* regular expression, simply use `^'pattern1'|\d{4}`. The first match will contain `'pattern1'` in the beginning of the string, remaining ones, the years (post AD 999).

A more correct solution would be to *match* a line, containing `'pattern1'` and dates, *capturing* `'pattern1'` and the tail containing dates (e.g. `^(?<head>'pattern1')(?<tail>(?:.*?\d{4})+.*$)`, and then *matching* dates in the tail (just `\d{4}`). But the exact code depends on your environment.